# How to automatically add properties to an object that is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to automatically add properties to objects if they don't already exist?

Consider the following example:

```js
var test = {}
test.hello.world = "Hello doesn't exist!"
```

This doesn't work because `hello` isn't defined.

The reason why I'm asking this is because I have some existing objects for which I don't know if they allready have `hello` or not. I actually have a lot of these objects in different parts of my code.
It is very annoying to always check if `hello` exists and if it doesn't create a new object like:

```js
var test = {}
if(test.hello === undefined) test.hello = {}
test.hello.world = "Hello World!"
```

Is there a way to automatically create an object like `hello` in this example?

I mean something like that in php:

```php
$test = array();  
$test['hello']['world'] = "Hello world";   
var_dump($test);
```

Output:

```js
array(1) {
  ["hello"] => array(1) {
    ["world"] => string(11) "Hello world"
  }
}
```

Ok it's an array but in js arrays it is the same problem as with objects.

Comment: function existcheckthingy(x, y, z){ if(x === undefined) x = {}; x.y = z; } used as existcheckthingy(test.hello, world, "Hello doesn't exist!");

Comment: @bobbybee That won't work. It will create a new object `x` in the scope of the `existcheckthingy` function, but that will not then be attached to the `test` object. You can do better by using the "array-like" notation: `existcheckthingy(a,x,y,z) { if (a[x] === undefined) a[x] = {}; a[x][y] = z;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069584/js-build-object-path-in-property-assignment

Comment: @Jeff oops, forgot about that :3

Comment: consider lodash 'set'

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
var test = {};
test.hello = test.hello || {};
test.hello.world = "Hello world!";
```

If `test.hello` is undefined, it gets set to an empty object.

If `test.hello` was previously defined, it stays unchanged.

```
var test = {
  hello : {
    foobar : "Hello foobar"
  }
};

test.hello = test.hello || {};
test.hello.world = "Hello World";

console.log(test.hello.foobar); // this is still defined;
console.log(test.hello.world); // as is this.
```

Comment: this is pretty much idiomatic JS

Comment: It's very short thanks for that. But It is still a manual check. Isn't it possibly without?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder no, this is as short as it gets.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder: Not as far as I know.

Comment: @xbonez NB: not "defined" - _truthy_.  However an empty object is actually truthy.

Comment: Is it possible to do this: `var hi = test.hello = test.hello || {};` The desired effect would be to define `test.hello` if not already defined, but then also assign it to the variable `hi`.

Comment: @Lopsided I'm not sure but you could try it to verify

Comment: @xbonez I have never seen this done before, very interesting. Do you have any references that we could check to read about this approach? Is this official JavaScript method or just something that happens to work?

Comment: @einar: I'll try to find some reference but this is a very well known and standard way of doing this. its used heavily in libraries like jquery, angularjs etc.

Comment: Thank you guy ! You made my day )) Allah balalarini saxlasin ;)

Comment: It will be better if you used the nullish coalescing operator instead of the logical OR operator

Answer (score 83):

You can use the Logical nullish assignment (??=):

```
var test = {};
(test.hello ??= {}).world ??= "Hello doesn't exist!";
```

Comment: This is the best answer as of 2021

Comment: Best answer. Should be go up!!

Comment: Should be `(test.hello ??= {}).world = "Hello doesn't exist!";` otherwise if `test.hello.world` already exists it will not be overwritten.

Comment: be aware that this also sets `test.hello` if it is `null` (not **only** if it is `undefined`)

Answer (score 22):

New object

```
myObj = {};
```

recursive function

```
function addProps(obj, arr, val) {

    if (typeof arr == 'string')
        arr = arr.split(".");

    obj[arr[0]] = obj[arr[0]] || {};

    var tmpObj = obj[arr[0]];

    if (arr.length > 1) {
        arr.shift();
        addProps(tmpObj, arr, val);
    }
    else
        obj[arr[0]] = val;

    return obj;

}
```

Call it with a dot notated string

```
addProps(myObj, 'sub1.sub2.propA', 1);
```

or with an array

```
addProps(myObj, ['sub1', 'sub2', 'propA'], 1);
```

and your object will look like this

```
myObj = {
  "sub1": {
    "sub2": {
      "propA": 1
    }
  }
};
```

It works with non-empty objects too!

Comment: this actually works really neatly, and updates the correct value without breaking my object.

Comment: For anyone implementing this in Typescript, the object's type can be defined as `type RecursiveObject = { [key: number | string]: RecursiveObject | any };`

Answer (score 7):

You won't be able to do this without some sort of function, as JavaScript doesn't have a generic getter/setter method for objects (Python, for example, has `__getattr__`). Here's one way to do it:

```
function add_property(object, key, value) {
    var keys = key.split('.');

    while (keys.length > 1) {
        var k = keys.shift();

        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            object[k] = {};
        }

        object = object[k];
    }

    object[keys[0]] = value;
}
```

If you really want to, you could add it to the prototype of `Object`. You can call it like so:

```
> var o = {}
> add_property(o, 'foo.bar.baz', 12)
> o.foo.bar.baz
12
```

Comment: something is wrong with this function when used repetitively on the same object

Comment: @RozzA: Thanks for catching that bug, it's now fixed.

Comment: @Blender is there a possibility to read value of property like `read_property(o, 'foo.bar.baz')` will return 12 ? after a property  is added

Answer (score 7):

Here's a cool version with proxies:

```
const myUpsert = (input) => {
    const handler = {
        get: (obj, prop) => {
            obj[prop] = obj[prop] || {};
            return myUpsert(obj[prop]);
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(input, handler);
};
```

And you use it like this:

```
myUpsert(test).hello.world = '42';
```

This will add all the missing properties as empty objects, and leave the existing ones untouched.  It's really just a proxied version of the classic `test.hello = test.hello || {}`, albeit much slower ([See benchmark here](https://repl.it/repls/ExtrasmallEarnestAgent).) But it's also much nicer to look at, especially if you'll be doing it more than one level deep.  I wouldn't pick it for performance-heavy data crunching, but it's probably fast enough for a front-end state update (as in Redux).

Note that there's some implicit assumptions here:

1. The intervening properties are either objects or non-existent.  This will choke if `test.hello` is a string, for example.
2. That you always want to be doing this for as long as you're using the Proxy instead of the original object.

These are pretty easily mitigated if you only use it in well-bounded contexts (like a reducer body) where there's little chance of accidentally returning the Proxy, and not much else you would want to do with the object.

Answer (score 5):

Well you could extend the prototype of `Object` with a function that return a property, but adds it first, if it doesn't exist:

```
Object.prototype.getOrCreate = function (prop) {
    if (this[prop] === undefined) {
        this[prop] = {};
    }
    return this[prop];
};

var obj = {};

obj.getOrCreate("foo").getOrCreate("bar").val = 1;
```

Comment: this seems like a great solution however it breaks DataTables for some reason.  Is messing with object internals considered a good idea normally?

Comment: This is why extending native objects can be a bad idea, because methods might overlap.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = {}
if(!test.hasOwnProperty('hello')) {
    test.hello = {};
}
test.hello.world = "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add a property `hello` whose value is `{world: 'Hello world!'}` to the test object, if it doesn't exist. If you have a lot of these objects, you can just iterate over them and apply this function. Note: uses [lodash.js](http://lodash.com/)

```
var test = {};
_.defaults(test, { hello: {world: 'Hello world!'} });
```

Which is actually a convenience method for saying:

```
var defaults = _.partialRight(_.assign, function(a, b) {
  return typeof a == 'undefined' ? b : a;
});        
defaults(test, { hello: {world: 'Hello world!'} });
```

Note: `_.defaults` uses loops to achieve the same thing as the second block.

P.S. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197858/1218080

Comment: _.set({}, 'a.b.c.d', "asdf") will create '{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":"asdf"}}}}', and might be more what he was looking for

Answer (score 2):

```js
let test = {};
test = {...test, hello: {...test.hello, world: 'Hello does exist!'}};
console.log(test);
```

When using the spread operator, the value can be undefined, it'll automatically create an object.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something, really custom as well, but it works as far as I have tested.

```
function dotted_put_var(str,val) {
    var oper=str.split('.');
    var p=window;
    for (var i=0;i<oper.length-1;i++) {
        var x=oper[i];
        p[x]=p[x]||{};
        p=p[x];
    }
    p[oper.pop()]=val;
}
```

Then, a complex variable can be set like this, ensuring that every links will be created if not already:

```
dotter_put_var('test.hello.world', 'testvalue'); // test.hello.world="testvalue";
```

See this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8fvT/2/).

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
Object.prototype.initProperty = function(name, defaultValue) {
  if (!(name in this)) this[name] = defaultValue;
};
```

You can later do f.e.:

```
var x = {a: 1};
x.initProperty("a", 2); // will not change property a
x.initProperty("b", 3); // will define property b
console.log(x); // => {a: 1, b: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = {}
test.hello.world = "Hello doesn't exist!"
```

This will throw an error obviously as you didn't defined the test.hello

Firstly you need to need define the hello key then inside you can assign any key.
But if you want to create key if not exists then you can do following thing

```
test.hello = test.hello || {};
```

The above statement will create the test.hello object if not defined and if it is defined then it will assign the same value as it is previously

Now you can assign any new key inside the test.hello

```
test.hello.world = "Everything works perfect";

test.hello.world2 = 'With another key too, it works perfect';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) from Lodash

```js
 _.set({}, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
// => { a: [{ b: { c: 4 } }] }
```

Comment: Interesting library for JS ! thx for posting this..

Comment: Happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes on [columbus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643965/automatically-create-object-if-undefined#answer-34205057) to allow create arrays:

```js
function addProps(obj, arr, val) {

  if (typeof arr == 'string')
    arr = arr.split(".");

  var tmpObj, isArray = /^(.*)\[(\d+)\]$/.exec(arr[0])
  if (isArray && !Number.isNaN(isArray[2])) {
    obj[isArray[1]] = obj[isArray[1]] || [];
    obj[isArray[1]][isArray[2]] = obj[isArray[1]][isArray[2]] || {}
    tmpObj = obj[isArray[1]][isArray[2]];
  } else {
    obj[arr[0]] = obj[arr[0]] || {};
    tmpObj = obj[arr[0]];
  }

  if (arr.length > 1) {
    arr.shift();
    addProps(tmpObj, arr, val);
  } else
    obj[arr[0]] = val;

  return obj;

}


var myObj = {}
addProps(myObj, 'sub1[0].sub2.propA', 1)
addProps(myObj, 'sub1[1].sub2.propA', 2)

console.log(myObj)
```

I think that is possible to allow use "sub1[].sub2..." to just push into the `sub1` array, instead of specify the index, but that's enough for me now.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1:

Use `Object.assign`:

```js
var test = {};
Object.assign(test, { hello: { world: "hello world" }});

console.log(test.hello.world); // "hello world"
```

#### Option 2:

Use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
var test = {};
test = {...test, ...{ hello: { world: "hello world" }}};

console.log(test.hello.world); // "hello world"
```