# upsert object field in node elegantly

Tags: javascript, node.js

Simple question: writing code in javascript, I find myself write the same lines of code over and over:

```
if (!obj.field) obj.field={};
obj.field.inner_field='val';
```

In order to protect myself from cases where obj.field is not defined. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `Object.assign`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value of javascript object attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600868/set-default-value-of-javascript-object-attributes)

Comment: Possible solution: `obj.field = Object.assign({}, {inner_field: "val"})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically create object if undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643965/automatically-create-object-if-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator.

```js
var obj = {};
    
if (!('field' in obj)) {
    obj.field = {};
}
obj.field.inner_field = 'val';
console.log(obj);
```

Or you can use `Object.assign()` (notes: this overwrites possibly existing fields).

```js
var obj = {};
obj.field = Object.assign({}, {inner_field: 'val'})
console.log(obj);
```

Alternatively you can use:

```js
var obj  = {};
obj.field  = obj.field  || {};
obj.field.inner_field  = 'val';
console.log(obj);
```

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: `obj.field = Object.assign({}, {inner_field: 'val'})` overwrites possibly existing `field`. OP uses `if` obviously because he does not want to overwrite the whole object, just a single key. Performance aside you could do `obj.field = Object.assign(obj.field || {}, {inner_field : 'val'});` to keep other keys.

Comment: @vesse thanks for your comment I made an edit to my answer :)

Comment: My variant is `obj.field = Object.assign({}, obj.field, {inner_field: 'val'})`. Your first and third variants have a little defect if `obj.field` is `number` or `string`.