# Object value in memory (stack?) in recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I found a good piece of code on SO that I only partially understand. If you could help me understand what is happening with `myObj` in the second loop of this recursive function when the function no longer points to `myObj` (instead it points to `tmpObj` yet it still adds onto it.

```
  var myObj = {};

function addProps(obj, arr, val) { // in the first run obj = myObj

    if (typeof arr == 'string')
        arr = arr.split(".");

    obj[arr[0]] = obj[arr[0]] || {};

    var tmpObj = obj[arr[0]];

    if (arr.length > 1) {
        arr.shift();
        addProps(tmpObj, arr, val); // whilst recursing, tmpObj becomes obj (as function parameter), so why myObj keeps being changed as well?
    }
    else
        obj[arr[0]] = val;

    return obj;

};

addProps(myObj, 'sub1.sub2.propA', 1);
```

Link to the original piece of code : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34205057

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Your question can be answered very quickly and easily with your step-debugger. You should always try and solve your problems with a step debugger before coming to StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: I have use the debugger, and it increases the myObj. I just want to know why as the new tmpObj is not pointing to myObj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have a nested object and mutate the inner one, there is no copying involved... the outer one still points to the same (now mutated) inner object, e.g.:

```js
const myObj = {a: {b: 'c'}}
const tmpObj = myObj.a
tmpObj.b = 'd'
console.log('original mutated after changing the inner object:', myObj)

const copyObj = Object.assign({}, myObj.a) // or {...myObj.a}
copyObj.b = 'e'
console.log('original NOT mutated after changing a copy:', myObj)
```