# Mirth JSON Object Population

Tags: javascript, mirth

I need help trying to populate this object structure.

```
{
   "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "Who seeks a faultless friend RESTs friendless.",
       "description": "Creating an issue and setting time tracking fields",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't like it. I get "Cannot read property project from undefined".

```
var newObject = {code:{}};
newObject['fields']['project']['key']="X";
newObject['fields']['summary']= "Y";
newObject['fields']['issuetype']['name'] = "Z";
newObject['fields']['assignee']['name'] = "A";
newObject['fields']['priority']['name'] = "B";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically add properties to an object that is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643965/how-to-automatically-add-properties-to-an-object-that-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot read property project from undefined" means that you are trying to access a value from a property that does not exist. In your context, javascript is trying to access 'project', but the property preceding project, aka newObject['fields'], is undefined.

You are trying to populate your object a little to fast hehe. You have to create each property before adding any keys & values. In other words, go step by step.

There is a couple ways to address this problem, here are two:

**Solution #1**

Add properties when you create newObject, like so:

```
 var newObject = {
    fields: {
    project: {},
    issuetype: {},
    assignee: {},
    priority: {}
  }
};
```

And then proceed with the same code you had & populate keys inside each properties.

**Solution #2**

```
var newObject = {code:{}};
newObject.fields = {}; // First create the property
newObject['fields']['project'] = {}; // Then add new keys & values
newObject['fields']['project']['key']= "X";

newObject.fields.issuetype = {}; // First create the proprerty issuetype
newObject.fields.assignee= {}; // First create the proprerty assignee
newObject.fields.priority= {}; // First create the proprerty priority
newObject['fields']['issuetype']['name'] = "Z"; // Then add new keys & values
newObject['fields']['assignee']['name'] = "A"; // ...
newObject['fields']['priority']['name'] = "B"; // ...
```

Comment: Why mix `[]` and dot syntax here?

Comment: To show both methods work. I usually use dot syntax but OP seemed to use [] syntax.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you!